# Video is not displaying?

Tags: css, html, video

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240" />
  </object> 
</video>
```

I am very new to video concept,I got this code from google.

But Video is not displaying .

I am using html5.
Please help me

Comment: are you sure your browser supports the video tag?

Comment: I checked in google chrome ,its not working,I am very new to video concept,is there any plugins needed for this

Comment: no, have you applied the src paths?

Comment: yea,for testing ,i kept both html and video in the same folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

Note: You need to convert the movie.mp4 in movie.ogg with a tool not just to change extension.